# ValueError: The model is not configured to compute accuracy. You should pass `metrics=["accuracy"]` to the `model.compile()` method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am very new in Deep Learning:
I am doing a deep learning course on Udemy. once I execute my code, it says:

ValueError: The model is not configured to compute accuracy. You should pass `metrics=["accuracy"]` to the `model.compile()` method.

I tried to change 'accuracy' into 'acc', It gives me no more error, but the code is super fast, it shows me only 10 epochs instead of 100. besides I was expecting accuracy around 83% but I am having something like 79%.

can someone please help me?

''''

```
import keras
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

def build_classifier():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim= 11))
    classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn= build_classifier, batch_size=10 , nb_epoch=100)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = x_train, y = y_train, cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
```

''''
This is my fulltraceback:

''''

```
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = x_train, y = y_train, cv=10, n_jobs=-1, verbose=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-138-36c63e93365e>", line 1, in <module>
    accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = x_train, y = y_train, cv=10, n_jobs=-1, verbose=0)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 389, in cross_val_score
    error_score=error_score)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 235, in cross_validate
    for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1017, in __call__
    self.retrieve()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 909, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 562, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 435, in result
    return self.__get_result()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception

ValueError: The model is not configured to compute accuracy. You should pass `metrics=["accuracy"]` to the `model.compile()` method.
''''
```

I also tried this:
'

```
try:

    accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = x_train, y = y_train, cv=10, n_jobs=-1, verbose=0)
except ValueError as e:
    print ("ValueError:", e)
ValueError: The model is not configured to compute accuracy. You should pass `metrics=["accuracy"]` to the `model.compile()` method.
```

'

Comment: Can you include the full traceback in your question?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I'm sorry what do you mean by full traceback? con you explain briefly?

Comment: The full call stacktrace, it starts with "Traceback (most recent call last)", what you included in your title is just the exception error, which is not all the information available.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro : if I understood you correctly this is the full call trace back:

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I edited the question and added the fulltraceback

Comment: Ok, one thing I just noticed is that you are mixing imports between keras and tf.keras, you should not do that, use imports from either keras or tf.keras

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, Thank you so much. I think that was my answer, the error is gone. it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your imports you are mixing imports between the `keras` and `tf.keras` packages, that is actually **not** supported, you should choose one and make all imports from the selected package.